# I get weird perspective using GLM where the depth is flipped. Please help

Tags: opengl, perspective, glm

The depth is rendered wrong and I can't figure out why.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace glm;
int width = 640;
int height = 480;
float aspect = (float)width/height;
int fps = 60;

void start(){
  glClearColor(0.0f,0.2f,0.6f,1);
  glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
  glFrontFace(GL_CW);
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  mat4 projectionMatrix = perspective(radians(60.0f),aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
  mat4 modelViewMatrix = translate(vec3(0,-25,-100));
  modelViewMatrix *= rotate(radians(50.0f),vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
  modelViewMatrix *= rotate(radians(-90.0f),vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
  mat4 modelViewProjMatrix = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix;

  Shader shader;
  shader.load("vertex.glsl","fragment.glsl");
  shader.bind();
  shader.uniform("modelViewProjMatrix",value_ptr(modelViewProjMatrix));

  Model model;
  model.load("res/bob.md5mesh");

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  model.render();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mainloop(int val){
  glutTimerFunc(1000/fps,mainloop,val);
}
int main(int argc, char* args[]){
  glutInit(&argc,args);
  glutInitContextVersion(3,0);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(width,height); 
  glutCreateWindow("Test"); 
  glewInit();

  start();
  glutTimerFunc(1000/fps,mainloop,0);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0; 
}
```

[image]

However, I found a way to fix it by multiplying the perspective by scale(1,1,-1),
but it seems kind of a hack to me.

```
mat4 projectionMatrix = perspective(radians(60.0f),aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f) * scale(vec3(1,1,-1));
mat4 modelViewMatrix = translate(vec3(0,-25,100));
```

[image]

I'd really appreciate it if someone can tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Disable `GL_CULL_FACE`, if this fixes it, your faces are clockwise, not counterclockwise.

Comment: You right! the faces are backwards, how silly of me. I thought it was the depth. Thanks a bunch tkausl. I'm using assimp library to load the model, not sure why it's loading the faces clockwise.

Comment: So I used the flag aiProcess_FlipWindingOrder when loading the model using Assimp, but it suppose to load the faces clockwise where before it was counterclockwise, so I'm still confused

Comment: @Tai Swapping from clockwise -> counterclockwise and counterclockwise -> clockwise are inverse operations. Therefore, even though it was *designed* with the intent of flipping counterclockwise faces (how they *should* be stored) to clockwise faces (which some rendering engines might expect), it will work in your favor in the opposite situation as well. However, this is extra processing that you could avoid by simply storing your faces in counterclockwise order to begin with. This can be fixed with most model editors, and is probably one of the export options.